# how do i put button at bottom of screen using autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

What i need to make a button at bottom of screen but I've encountered an issue with iPhone 4s so please take a look at screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u1eV.png)

so I've tried another solution which pin the button from top to the last stack-view here I've got an issue with iPhone 7 " inequality constraint ambiguity" when i change constraint from 'Equal' into 'greater than or Equal' to put it at bottom of screen as shown in screenshots

[iPhone4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTJWp.png)
[iPhone7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2odv.png)

what should i do ?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

An NSGridView would be perfect for this, but no such thing exists in iOS.

I would create a label and a textbox, put a vertical spacing constraint between them, then embed the two controls in a vertical stack. The stack should have a "Fill" alignment and "Equal spacing" in distribution.

Then copy and paste the stack for each of the control groups (First name, Last name, Phone, Email and Password). Select all the Stacks and embed them into another vertical stack. The stack should have a "Fill" alignment and "Equal spacing" in distribution. Constrain the stack to the top, leading, bottom and trailing edges of the view. Now you should be able to control the distance between the control groups with the spacing property in the stack view.

Comment: Thank you for reply I wanna make the distance between the button and the last stack-view (Password Stackview) is double space as shown in first screen shot in iPhone 7

Comment: Hard to help, when I can’t see the constraints affecting the Register button.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding UiView and add button inside that UIView and add constrains to based on the place where you was need to place your button.. You can add bottom space to superview and fix the issue